# Inject external xml into main xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, external, xslt-1.0, document, code-injection

I have my xsl to transform xml_file_1. 
I have xml_file_2 to be included into the output of the xsl.

for example, the structure of the output file is:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <!-- inject external xml here -->
        <C/>
    </B>
</A>
```

How to do this?

I tried to use the following receipt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('external.xml')/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but it just replaces output file with the content of external file.
I tried different variations of the above template like pointing match="/" to the node I need to insert (match="/A/B") but with no result.

P.S. I am going to remove the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` from external file with sed before using it in xsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think injection point should be marked by some element like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <InjectionPoint />
        <C/>
    </B>
</A>
```

Let external.xml be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExternaFile>
    <Content1 />
    <Content2 />
</ExternaFile>
```

Then slightly modified [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) could be used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Replacing inject point element-->
    <xsl:template match="InjectionPoint">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('external.xml')" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <ExternaFile>
            <Content1/>
            <Content2/>
        </ExternaFile>
        <C/>
    </B>
</A>
```

BTW, you don't need to strip xml prologue by sed.

Edit: I you don't want use special element for marking the right place you could use template like

```
<!--or without "inject" element -->
<xsl:template match="B[parent::A]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('external.xml')" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But several problems could occur (e.g. when there are more B elements in A element, when there are several A elements containing B element etc.).